# How do I change owner and group owner of files and directories?

Tags: shell, scripting, permissions, chown, chgrp

I want to change the owner and the group owner for all the files in the current working directories with a single line command. I don't want to have double line as follows;

sudo chown you <some_file>
chgrp new_group some_file

Comment: `man chown` is worth a read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo chown you:new_group some_file`

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code

```
sudo chown new_user:new_group *
```

sudo  = `super user do`
chown = `change owner`
'*'   = `target all the files in the working directory`